# AngularJS cannot update data attributes?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a input element, which use the type-ahead plugin from bootstrap. **I want to set the data-source attribute as the user typing. The effect is like instance search.**

```
<input id="test" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="{{titles}}"/>
```

And in my AngularJS controller, I have

```
$scope.titles = my_array_object
```

After above code is executed, I see in Chrome developer tool that the *data-source* attribute is set correctly.

But in Chrome console, when I execute

```
$('#test').data('source')
```

the return value is "", an empty string

What is the correct way to set the element attribute?

Comment: Could you explain what you are attempting to do ? As in, why you are attempting to set the data attributes on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this : http://plnkr.co/edit/ASeDxB5445HeiLKOq409?p=preview

```
 var myApp = angular.module("app",[]);

  myApp.directive('moDataSource',function() {
        return {
          restrict:"A", 
          scope:{
            moDataSource:"=",
          },              
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var typeahead = elem.typeahead().data("typeahead");             
            typeahead.source = scope.moDataSource;     
          }         
        };
        });

   function MainCtrl($scope) {       
       $scope.addItem = function (item) {
         if(item.length > 0)
            $scope.array.push(item);
       };
       $scope.array = ['Safari',"Internet Explorer","FireFox","Chrome"];     
   }
```

Comment: Have the same problem, it look like Angular in Firefox don't interpolate values inside data attributes, you need to use different one.